# Verify a string as a valid UUID in Swift

Tags: swift, uuid

Given an supplied `String`, how can I verify wether the `String` is a valid UUID in Swift?

A valid UUID (as far as I know) could be:

```
33041937-05b2-464a-98ad-3910cbe0d09e
3304193705b2464a98ad3910cbe0d09e
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could use `UUID`

```
var uuid = UUID(uuidString: yourString)
```

This will return nil if `yourString` is not a valid UUID

Note: this only validates the first case you presented, not the second but adding the dashes yourself is trivial.

Comment: `NSUUID(uuidString: yourString)` with Swift 3

Comment: `UUID(uuidString: yourString)` in Swift 4

Comment: is there a way to check for UUID version?

Answer (score 6):

The following is updated for Swift 4.0 to determine if a string is a valid UUID.

```
let uuidHyphens = "33041937-05b2-464a-98ad-3910cbe0d09e"
let uuidNoHyphens = "3304193705b2464a98ad3910cbe0d09e"

if UUID(uuidString: uuidHyphens) != nil {
    print("UUID string with hypens is valid") // Will be valid
} else {
    print("UUID string with hypens is not valid")
}

// In this scenario, the UUID will be nil,
if UUID(uuidString: uuidNoHyphens) != nil {
    print("UUID string with no hypens is valid")
} else {
    print("UUID string with no hypens is not valid") // Will not be valid
}
```

The string passed in to the [UUID init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid/1779760-init) must contain hyphens, otherwise the check will fail. If you are expecting strings without hypens, then you can utilize an approach such as [what is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103454/how-to-add-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-string-in-swift) to add hypens to a string if it satisfies a length of 32.

The relevant section from Apple's documentation:

> Create a UUID from a string such as
>   “E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F”.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote the extension below to make UUID Strings

```
extension String {
  var uuid: String? {
    var string = self
    var index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 8)
    for _ in 0..<4 {
      string.insert("-", at: index)
      index = string.index(index, offsetBy: 5)
    }
    // The init below is used to check the validity of the string returned.
    return UUID(uuidString: string)?.uuidString
  }
}
```

Comment: var string = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: ""); // because some other formats might put the - in other places (8-4-8-12 instead of 8-4-4-4-12).