# How to insert character into string in Swift 2.0?

Tags: swift2

This function takes in an Int like `324543` and returns a String like "$3245.43"

My attempt is below, but Swift 2 does not like `atIndex: 0`

How would I go about inserting characters into a string instead?

> ```
> func stylizeCents (cent: Int) -> String {
>     var styledCents = String(cent)
>     let dollarSign : Character = "$"
>     let dot : Character = "."
>     let count = styledCents.characters.count
>     styledCents.insert(dollarSign, atIndex: 0) // error
>     styledCents.insert(dot, atIndex: count-1) // error
> }
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a character at a particular index in string in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103454/how-to-add-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This appears to have already been solved in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466063/939872).

> ### Swift 2.0
>
> You can use a string extension:
>
> ```
> extension String {
>     func insert(string:String,ind:Int) -> String {
>         return  String(self.characters.prefix(ind)) + string + String(self.characters.suffix(self.characters.count-ind))
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> used like:
>
> ```
> var url = "http://www.website.com"
> url = url.insert("s", ind: 4) // outputs https://www.website.com
> ```