# Insert character after first N characters in Swift

Tags: swift, regex, string

I have an String returned `let myData = "0000006215342"` and I want to separate only the firs characters defined by a String extension method

```
    func separating(every: Int, separator: String) -> String {
       let regex = #"(.{\#(every)})(?=.)"#
       return self.replacingOccurrences(of: regex, with: "$1\(separator)", options: [.regularExpression])
    }
```

The actual result calling my method are like

```
mylabel.text = myData.separating(every: 6, separator: " ")
```

The actual result of applying my method are `"000000 621534 2"` but this is wrong because I want to separate only the first characters like `"000000 6215342"` how I can edit my regex to separate my first N characters ?

Comment: Do you really need a regex to do so? Why not just insert at index 6 a space?

Comment: @Larme It is not necessary to use regex, it is a possible solution that I apply

Comment: `str.prefix(6) + " " + str.dropFirst(6)`  should be enough, you might want to check before hand if the lenght is greater than 6.

Comment: You are the one saying replace all occurrences. If you don't want that, don't say it! Just replace the first occurrence.

Comment: or `str.insert(" ", at: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 6))`  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103454/how-to-add-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-string-in-swift

Comment: Awesome, this solutions works! Thank you guys

Comment: @rxDVZ You just need to anchor your regex pattern to the start of the string `#"^(.{\#(every)})"#`

Comment: Given the beahviour you described, isn't the "every" in `separating(every:separator:)` misleading? You're not separating every group of 6, only the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to anchor your regex pattern to the start of the string:

```
let regex = #"^(.{\#(every)})"#
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple to do without any regular expressions being required, just using a String slice:

```swift
extension String {
    func separating(every groupSize: Int, separator: String) -> String {
        guard let separatorIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: groupSize, limitedBy: endIndex) else {
            return self // The string is too short so no separators are necessary 
        }
        return String(self[..<separatorIndex] + Substring(separator) + self[separatorIndex...])
    }
}

let myData = "0000006215342"
let result = myData.separating(every: 6, separator: " ")
print(result) // => "000000 6215342"
```

Comment: Note that it would be much easier to simply using `replacingCharacters(in:)` range and pass an empty range. `replacingCharacters(in: separatorIndex..<separatorIndex, with: separator)`. Btw you can use `UnboundedRange` [operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nshostingview) to create a substring `separator[...]`

Comment: @LeoDabus “ Btw you can use UnboundedRange operator to create a substring separator[...]” I like that style personally, but I find that it less clearly expresses the intent than just specifying “substring” explicitly. It’s not all that much shorter. As for using replacingCharacters: that’s clever, I love it.